# GitActions workflow: cache is not passing between jobs

Tags: caching, github-actions

What I am trying to do is basically an **assembly line**: every job must build/maniuplate the provided files, the cache, that is **passed to the following job**.

This is my workflow:

```yaml
jobs:

  Job1_-_Prepearing_enviornment:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:

    - name: Get date for artifacts
      id: date
      run: echo "::set-output name=date::$(date +'%Y%m%d_%H%M%S')"

    - name: Extract branch name
      shell: bash
      run: echo "##[set-output name=branch;]$(echo ${GITHUB_REF#refs/heads/})"
      id: extract_branch

    - name: Generating build ID
      run: echo "${{ steps.extract_branch.outputs.branch }}-${{ steps.date.outputs.date }}"
    outputs:
      buildID: "${{ steps.extract_branch.outputs.branch }}-${{ steps.date.outputs.date }}"

    # In the last 3 steps I am generating a build specific key in order to not be confused with other running workflows

  Job2_-_Downloading_Sources:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: [Job1_-_Prepearing_enviornment]
    steps:

      # Here I download a global cache if it's existing (I am generating the global cache in a job not copypasted here)
      - uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: global-cache
        continue-on-error: true

      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Downloading sources
        run: |
          git pull
          git submodule init
          git submodule update
          sudo add-apt-repository ppa:alexlarsson/flatpak
          sudo apt-get update
          sudo apt install flatpak flatpak-builder p7zip-full
          sudo flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
          sudo flatpak install -y org.kde.Sdk//5.15-21.08 org.kde.Platform//5.15-21.08 io.qt.qtwebengine.BaseApp/x86_64/5.15-21.08 org.freedesktop.Sdk.Extension.llvm13
          sudo flatpak-builder --download-only --user --repo=local retrodeck-flatpak net.retrodeck.retrodeck.yml
          
      # Here I am using the key generated in the Job1 to save the cache
      - name: Generating build specific cache
        id: intenral-cache
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          path: /home/runner/work/RetroDECK
          key: ${{ needs.Job1_-_Prepearing_enviornment.outputs.buildID }}
          
  Job3_-_Building_part_1:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: [Job1_-_Prepearing_enviornment, Job2_-_Downloading_Sources]
    steps:

      # Here I am supposed to get the internal cache calling its key but this process is not working and the build stops
      - name: cache-cooker
        id: internal-cache
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          path: /home/runner/work/RetroDECK
          key: ${{ needs.Job1_-_Prepearing_enviornment.outputs.buildID }}

      - name: Initializing enviornment
        run: |
          git submodule init
          git submodule update
          sudo add-apt-repository ppa:alexlarsson/flatpak
          sudo apt-get update
          sudo apt install flatpak flatpak-builder p7zip-full
          sudo flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
          sudo flatpak install -y org.kde.Sdk//5.15-21.08 org.kde.Platform//5.15-21.08 io.qt.qtwebengine.BaseApp/x86_64/5.15-21.08 org.freedesktop.Sdk.Extension.llvm13
      - name: Bulding part 1 - Until melonds
        run: |
          cd /home/runner/work/RetroDECK/RetroDECK
          sudo flatpak-builder --build-only --stop-at=melonds --user --repo=local retrodeck-flatpak net.retrodeck.retrodeck.yml
```

As you can see from the comments in the code, the job3 cannot get the cache and I get this output from the GitAction log:

```
Run actions/cache@v2
  with:
    path: /home/runner/work/RetroDECK
    key: cooker-20220502_115338
Cache not found for input keys: cooker-20220502_115338
```

Then the job fails because it cannot find the needed files.

I am trying to use the Artifacts instead of the cache but it's too slow by zipping, uploading, downloading and unzipping, so maybe the cache it's a more straightforward way.

What am I doing wrong?
How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please copy a minimal reproducer directly into the question instead of linking. Please also copy the error messages directly into the question -- this makes it possible for other people with the same problem to find your question.